# VueJs / Vuex : Rendering list of items

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to render a list of **offers** from my **vuex store**. The problem is when i'm loading my *list of offers* page, they are not rendered.

Here is my code :

**offers.js**

```
export const namespaced = true

export const state = {}

export const mutations = {

  [types.UPDATE_OFFERS] (state, offers) {
    Object.assign(state, offers)
  }
}

export const actions = {

  async fetchOffers ({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/offers')
    commit(types.UPDATE_OFFERS, data)
  }
}
```

**offers.vue** (my page component)

```
<template>

            <div>

              <div v-if="offers"
                   v-for="offer in offers"
                   :key="offer.id">

                <div>

                  <div>

                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'offer', params: { offer: offer.id } }">
                       {{ offer.project }}
                    </router-link>

                  </div>

                  <div>

                    <div v-if="offer.versions[0] && offer.versions[0].status == 'edition'">
                       Validate the offer
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapState(['offers'])
  },

  beforeMount () {
    this.$store.dispatch('offers/fetchOffers')
  }
}
</script>
```

When i'm loading the page, I can see that the store as loaded the offers but the page doesnt render them. The weird thing is when I load the page ***offers*** then another page (example ***createAnOffer***) and then I come back to ***offers***, it renders the offers proplery.

I tried beforemount, beforeCreate, mounted, created.

I admit I have no clue what's going on.

Any tip ?

Thank you for your answers.

Louis

Comment: Can you edit and show the complete code for the `offers.vue` page?

Comment: i think the issue comes from combining `v-if` and `v-for` `v-if="offers" v-for="offer in offers" ` in the element

Comment: Updated. I tried to remove or switch places `v-if` but didn't work. Thanks for your help

Comment: what does `export const state = {}` contain inside it?

Comment: A list of objects (offers) : `{ 1 : { id: 1, project: 'ABC' }, 2 : { id: 2, project: 'DEF' }, ... } `

Comment: i think you should do `Object.assign(state.offers, offers)` inside the mutation

Comment: Not working. I think the problem is not in the store because its updating the **offer** store the right way

Comment: Well, believe it or not, I found a solution by adding a loader while dispatching the request... I've no clut what's going on